# Error in MPI program when using MPI_Reduce function of MPI_MAXLOC

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I want to use MPI_Reduce function find largest value and its PID(rank) at the same time, but the result shows it is not true, I don't know how to fix it, result:

```
PID:1, loc_num:2 
PID:2, loc_num:3 
PID:3, loc_num:4 
global data: 1 
coresponding PID: 0
```

my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //init MPI
    int PID, P;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);      
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &P);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &PID);
    struct{
        int value;
        int PID;
    } in, out;
    int value = 1;
    in.value = value;
    in.PID = PID;

   for(int i = 1; i <= P; i++){
        if (PID == i){                
            value = value + i;
            printf("PID:%d, loc_num:%d \n",PID, value);
        }

    } 
    MPI_Reduce(&in, &out, 1, MPI_2INT, MPI_MAXLOC, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    int max_PID = out.PID;
    int max_num = out.value;

    if (PID == 0){

        printf("global data: %d \n", max_num);
        printf("coresponding PID: %d \n",max_PID);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;       
}
```

I just follow the structure of `in.value= value and in.PID=PID and then,every PID calculate value=value+PID` so the answer is when `PID=1, loc=2;when PID=2, loc=3` ...next compare all of them by max, and sent them to `PID=0`

Comment: on every ranks, `in.value` is `1`, so what do you expect?

Comment: in.value is 1 right, and then, in.value=in.value+PID  and out.value=max(in.value), and I want to get corresponding PID

Comment: nope, you never `in.value = in.value = PID` !

Comment: what did you mean? in.value=in.value+PID; it can work

Comment: my point is you do not make such assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no error in the `MPI_Reduce` of your example. As **@Gilles** pointed out, the issue is you are not assigning the newly calculated `value` to `in.value`.

If you put the assignment statement after calculation as below, then everything work as expected.

```
   for(int i = 1; i <= P; i++){
        if (PID == i){
            value = value + i;
            printf("PID:%d, loc_num:%d \n",PID, value);
        }

    }
    in.value = value;
    in.PID = PID;
    MPI_Reduce(&in, &out, 1, MPI_2INT, MPI_MAXLOC, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

In your example below, you are not assigning the calculated values to the `in` struct object.

```
    in.value = value; // value is set as 1
    in.PID = PID;
    for(int i = 1; i <= P; i++){
    if (PID == i){
        value = value + i; // calculating the value but not assigning to in.value
        printf("PID:%d, loc_num:%d \n",PID, value);
       }
     }
    // uses the old value for in.value (i.e 1) for reduction
    MPI_Reduce(&in, &out, 1, MPI_2INT, MPI_MAXLOC, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```